# Can´t use selenium on vba

Tags: vba, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I'm used to running a script on vba using selenium in windows 7 with no problem, and since I installed Windows 10 a just can not open the Google Chrome automated window.

Already installed google chromedriver and the selenium library

Put the C:\....\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic on the environmental path

The Google Chrome is version 78.0.3904.108 and the chromedriver 78.0.3904.105, and people don't seem to have problems with that...

This is the start of the code, where crashes...

```
   Dim bot As New Selenium.ChromeDriver, posts As WebElements, post As WebElement, i As Integer, 
   mysheet As Worksheet, keys As Selenium.keys
   bot.Start "chrome", "https://valor.globo.com/impresso" **'it gots the error right here**
   bot.Get "/"
```

Anyone having this problem, knows what to do?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: unable to create session error?

Answer (score 0):

Check your version of Chrome, then download the ChromeDriver for your version.
This code should open Google.

The browser will close as soon as the Sub ends, so either declare the ChromeDriver on a global variable, or don't let the Sub end.

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyChromeDriver As ChromeDriver

sub MyCD
    Set MyChromeDriver = New ChromeDriver
    MyChromeDriver.Get "https://www.google.com/"
End Sub
```